# Find the least positive integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 30 \pmod{101}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the least positive integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 30 \pmod{101}$

This is the first time I have encountered this kind of problem, I have searched on the Internet but got no results. Is there a formula or an algorithm to solve this kind of problem? I would be very appreciative of your support!

Comment: @Moo All numbers of the form (101k+38) or (101k+63) satisfies the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! But can you give me hints on how to solve it, is there an algorithm to do it? Thanks!

Comment: A commonly used one is the [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) algorithm.

Comment: You want a solution for equation $x^2=101 k +30$. I do not see any way better than brute force. For example with $k=14$ we get $x=38$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "brute force" approach would be to try each $x$ from $1$ up to $101$. We can be sure that we won't have to try larger $x$, because if $x \equiv y \pmod{101}$, then $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod{101}$.

Here's a less tedious approach that relies on the facts that $101$ is prime and $101 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$. A proof of the following claim can be found in section 1.5 of [this textbook.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540556400)

**Claim**: Suppose $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, and suppose $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$. Then $x \equiv \pm a^{(p + 3)/8} \pmod{p}$ or $x \equiv \pm 2a \cdot (4a)^{(p - 5)/8} \pmod{p}$.

In our case, $p = 101$ and $a = 30$. You can quickly compute the values $a^{(p + 3)/8}$ and $2a \cdot (4a)^{(p - 5)/8}$ modulo $101$ using [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

If we were working modulo some other prime $p$, the [Tonelli-Shanks algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) would be a good approach. What if we were working modulo a large composite number $n$? It is conjectured that there *does not exist* an efficient algorithm for solving a given equation of the form $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{n}$. An efficient algorithm for that problem [could be used to factor large integers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/quadratic-residuosity-problem-reduction-to-integer-factorization) and thereby break important cryptosystems such as [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

Comment: Tonelli-Schanks works with this kind of primes because $101\equiv 1\mod 4$. If it is $p\equiv 3\mod 4$ then it is easier: $x^2\equiv a\mod p\to x\equiv p^{(a+1)/4}\mod p$.